# Place two \epsfboxes vertically centered next to each other

Tags: tex-core, metapost, cweb

The following problem has been brought to my attention by private communication: In the CWEB example program [skew-ternary-calc.w](https://github.com/ascherer/cwebtest/blob/master/skew-ternary-calc.w) (2015) by Don Knuth there are multiple occurrences of this construct:

```
$$\vcenter{\epsfbox{...}}\qquad\qquad
  \vcenter{\epsfbox{...}}$$
```

where `...` are names of MetaPost graphics from [skew-ternary-calc.mp](https://github.com/ascherer/cwebtest/blob/master/skew-ternarycalc.mp).

Running

```
for i in skew-ternary-calc; do mpost $i; cweave $i; tex $i; dvipdfm $i; done
```

produces extremely ‘overful boxes’ and results in a PDF with several displays where the right-hand graphic is outside the page frame.

Adding `\hbox{...}` around almost all the `\epsfbox{...}`es seems to fix this problem.

A simple `$$\vcenter{\epsfbox{...}}$$` works fine, but as soon as some other material comes alongside the `\epsfbox{...}` all hell breaks loose.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Most likely, `\vcenter{\hbox{\epsfbox{...}}}`, because `\epsfbox` does `\leavevmode`.

Comment: Btw: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that Don Knuth uses [the original `epsf.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/knuth/local/lib/epsf.tex) with a completely different definition of `\epsfbox` *without* `\leavevmode`.

So, instead of bothering “The Grand Wizard” with this issue and forcing him to update his local `epsf.tex`, I simply [add the missing `\hbox`es](https://github.com/ascherer/cwebtest/tree/fix-overful-hboxes) for those of us with an “updated” `epsf.tex`.

Comment: Knuth should have the final word on `epsf.tex`. He touched his version of this file on 27 Nov 2012, so he relies on the “old” behavior _without_ `\leavevmode`/`\hbox{...}`.

Comment: Knuth has fixed `skew-ternary-calc.w`, so that it should work with both versions of `epsf.tex`.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of `\epsfbox` in the `epsf.tex` file included in TeX Live (at `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/epsf/epsf.tex`, advertising `` This is `epsf.tex' v2.7.4 <14 February 2011> ``) is

```
\def \epsfbox #1{%
    \global \def \epsfllx {72}%
    \global \def \epsflly {72}%
    \global \def \epsfurx {540}%
    \global \def \epsfury {720}%
    \def \lbracket {[}%
    \def \testit {#1}%
    \ifx \testit \lbracket
        \let \next = \epsfgetlitbb
    \else
        \let \next = \epsfnormal
    \fi
    \next{#1}%
}%
```

Since you're calling it without `[`, we look at `\epsfnormal`:

```
\def \epsfnormal #1{%
    \epsfgetbb{#1}%
    \epsfsetgraph{#1}%
}%
```

No, it's still not the one; let's look at `\epsfsetgraph`:

```
\def \epsfsetgraph #1%
{%
   %
   % Make the vbox and stick in a \special that the DVI driver can
   % parse.  \vfil and \hfil are used to place the \special origin at
   % the lower-left corner of the vbox.  \epsfspecial can be redefined
   % to produce alternate \special syntaxes.
   %
   \ifvmode \leavevmode \fi
   \relax
   \hbox{% so we can put this in \begin{center}...\end{center}
   <...>
}%
```

As you see, this macro does `\leavevmode` when called in vertical mode, which is the case at the start of `\vcenter`. So the picture will be indented by the normal parindent and a one line paragraph will be formed, so the `\vcenter` box will have `\hsize` width.

Using `\vcenter{\hbox{\epsfbox{...}}}` is free from this defect; the box will have the same width as the image.

Comment: Curiosly enough, the “original” `epsf.tex` on CTAN is even more recent than that of TeXlive, having been changed by Knuth on 27 Nov 2012. `:o)`